# fit a ellipse in Python given a set of points xi=(xi,yi)

Tags: python, geometry, ellipse

I am computing a series of index from a 2D points (x,y). One index is the ratio between minor and major axis. To fit the ellipse i am using the following [post](http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html#the-approach)

when i run these function the final results looks strange because the center and the axis length are not in scale with the 2D points

```
center =  [  560415.53298363+0.j  6368878.84576771+0.j]
angle of rotation =  (-0.0528033467597-5.55111512313e-17j)
axes =  [0.00000000-557.21553487j  6817.76933256  +0.j]
```

thanks in advance for help

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig, inv

def fitEllipse(x,y):
    x = x[:,np.newaxis]
    y = y[:,np.newaxis]
    D =  np.hstack((x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    S = np.dot(D.T,D)
    C = np.zeros([6,6])
    C[0,2] = C[2,0] = 2; C[1,1] = -1
    E, V =  eig(np.dot(inv(S), C))
    n = np.argmax(np.abs(E))
    a = V[:,n]
    return a

def ellipse_center(a):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    num = b*b-a*c
    x0=(c*d-b*f)/num
    y0=(a*f-b*d)/num
    return np.array([x0,y0])

def ellipse_angle_of_rotation( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    return 0.5*np.arctan(2*b/(a-c))

def ellipse_axis_length( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    up = 2*(a*f*f+c*d*d+g*b*b-2*b*d*f-a*c*g)
    down1=(b*b-a*c)*( (c-a)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
    down2=(b*b-a*c)*( (a-c)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
    res1=np.sqrt(up/down1)
    res2=np.sqrt(up/down2)
    return np.array([res1, res2])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    points = [(560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258),
     (560036.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
     (560036.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
     (560036.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
     (560037.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
     (560037.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
     (560036.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
     (560036.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
     (560035.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
     (560035.4495758876, 6362062.390493258),
     (560034.9495758876, 6362062.390493258),
     (560034.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
     (560032.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
     (560032.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
     (560030.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
     (560030.4495758876, 6362061.390493258),
     (560029.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
     (560029.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
     (560029.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
     (560029.4495758876, 6362059.890493258),
     (560028.9495758876, 6362059.890493258),
     (560028.9495758876, 6362059.390493258),
     (560028.4495758876, 6362059.390493258),
     (560028.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
     (560027.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
     (560027.4495758876, 6362058.390493258),
     (560026.9495758876, 6362058.390493258),
     (560026.9495758876, 6362057.890493258),
     (560025.4495758876, 6362057.890493258),
     (560025.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
     (560023.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
     (560023.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
     (560023.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
     (560023.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
     (560024.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
     (560024.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
     (560024.9495758876, 6362063.390493258),
     (560024.9495758876, 6362064.390493258),
     (560025.4495758876, 6362064.390493258),
     (560025.4495758876, 6362065.390493258),
     (560025.9495758876, 6362065.390493258),
     (560025.9495758876, 6362065.890493258),
     (560026.4495758876, 6362065.890493258),
     (560026.4495758876, 6362066.890493258),
     (560026.9495758876, 6362066.890493258),
     (560026.9495758876, 6362068.390493258),
     (560027.4495758876, 6362068.390493258),
     (560027.4495758876, 6362068.890493258),
     (560027.9495758876, 6362068.890493258),
     (560027.9495758876, 6362069.390493258),
     (560028.4495758876, 6362069.390493258),
     (560028.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
     (560033.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
     (560033.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
     (560033.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
     (560033.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
     (560034.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
     (560034.4495758876, 6362071.390493258),
     (560034.9495758876, 6362071.390493258),
     (560034.9495758876, 6362071.890493258),
     (560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258)]


    a_points = np.array(points)
    x = a_points[:, 0]
    y = a_points[:, 1]
    from pylab import *
    plot(x,y)
    show()
    a = fitEllipse(x,y)
    center = ellipse_center(a)
    phi = ellipse_angle_of_rotation(a)
    axes = ellipse_axis_length(a)

    print "center = ",  center
    print "angle of rotation = ",  phi
    print "axes = ", axes

    from pylab import *
    plot(x,y)
    plot(center[0:1],center[1:], color = 'red')
    show()
```

each vertex is a xi,y,i point
[image]

plot of 2D point and center of fit ellipse
[image]

using OpenCV i have the following result:

```
import cv

PointArray2D32f = cv.CreateMat(1, len(points), cv.CV_32FC2)
for (i, (x, y)) in enumerate(points):
    PointArray2D32f[0, i] = (x, y)
    # Fits ellipse to current contour.
   (center, size, angle) = cv.FitEllipse2(PointArray2D32f)

(center, size, angle) 
((560030.625, 6362066.5),(10.480490684509277, 17.20206642150879),144.34889221191406)
```

Comment: Would you please post a figure to show how the result looks like?

Comment: done. I attached the figures

Comment: @Gianni: What's with the scale on that second graph?

Comment: @Eric: the 2 graph is the 2D Points and the center of the ellipse
[  560415.53298363+0.j  6368878.84576771+0.j]. The function adds +0.j at x and y

Answer (score 3):

The calculation for `fitEllipse` is returning bogus results because the values for `x` and `y` are very large compared to the variation between the values. If you try printing out the eigenvalues `E` for example, you see

```
array([  0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
         0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
         0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
        -1.36159790e-12 +8.15049878e-12j,
        -1.36159790e-12 -8.15049878e-12j,   1.18685632e-11 +0.00000000e+00j])
```

They are all practically zero! Clearly there is some kind of numerical inaccuracy here.

You can fix the problem by moving the mean of your data closer to zero so that the values are more "normal"-sized and the variation between the numbers becomes more significant.

```
x = a_points[:, 0]
y = a_points[:, 1]
xmean = x.mean()
ymean = y.mean()
x = x-xmean
y = y-ymean
```

You can then successfully find the center, phi and axes, and then re-shift the center back to (xmean, ymean):

```
center = ellipse_center(a)
center[0] += xmean
center[1] += ymean
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fitEllipse(x,y):
    x = x[:,np.newaxis]
    y = y[:,np.newaxis]
    D =  np.hstack((x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    S = np.dot(D.T,D)
    C = np.zeros([6,6])
    C[0,2] = C[2,0] = 2; C[1,1] = -1
    E, V =  linalg.eig(np.dot(linalg.inv(S), C))
    n = np.argmax(np.abs(E))
    a = V[:,n]
    return a

def ellipse_center(a):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    num = b*b-a*c
    x0=(c*d-b*f)/num
    y0=(a*f-b*d)/num
    return np.array([x0,y0])

def ellipse_angle_of_rotation( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    return 0.5*np.arctan(2*b/(a-c))

def ellipse_axis_length( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    up = 2*(a*f*f+c*d*d+g*b*b-2*b*d*f-a*c*g)
    down1=(b*b-a*c)*( (c-a)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
    down2=(b*b-a*c)*( (a-c)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
    res1=np.sqrt(up/down1)
    res2=np.sqrt(up/down2)
    return np.array([res1, res2])

def find_ellipse(x, y):
    xmean = x.mean()
    ymean = y.mean()
    x -= xmean
    y -= ymean
    a = fitEllipse(x,y)
    center = ellipse_center(a)
    center[0] += xmean
    center[1] += ymean
    phi = ellipse_angle_of_rotation(a)
    axes = ellipse_axis_length(a)
    x += xmean
    y += ymean
    return center, phi, axes

if __name__ == '__main__':

    points = [(560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258),
     (560036.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
     (560036.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
     (560036.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
     (560037.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
     (560037.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
     (560036.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
     (560036.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
     (560035.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
     (560035.4495758876, 6362062.390493258),
     (560034.9495758876, 6362062.390493258),
     (560034.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
     (560032.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
     (560032.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
     (560030.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
     (560030.4495758876, 6362061.390493258),
     (560029.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
     (560029.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
     (560029.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
     (560029.4495758876, 6362059.890493258),
     (560028.9495758876, 6362059.890493258),
     (560028.9495758876, 6362059.390493258),
     (560028.4495758876, 6362059.390493258),
     (560028.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
     (560027.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
     (560027.4495758876, 6362058.390493258),
     (560026.9495758876, 6362058.390493258),
     (560026.9495758876, 6362057.890493258),
     (560025.4495758876, 6362057.890493258),
     (560025.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
     (560023.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
     (560023.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
     (560023.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
     (560023.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
     (560024.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
     (560024.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
     (560024.9495758876, 6362063.390493258),
     (560024.9495758876, 6362064.390493258),
     (560025.4495758876, 6362064.390493258),
     (560025.4495758876, 6362065.390493258),
     (560025.9495758876, 6362065.390493258),
     (560025.9495758876, 6362065.890493258),
     (560026.4495758876, 6362065.890493258),
     (560026.4495758876, 6362066.890493258),
     (560026.9495758876, 6362066.890493258),
     (560026.9495758876, 6362068.390493258),
     (560027.4495758876, 6362068.390493258),
     (560027.4495758876, 6362068.890493258),
     (560027.9495758876, 6362068.890493258),
     (560027.9495758876, 6362069.390493258),
     (560028.4495758876, 6362069.390493258),
     (560028.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
     (560033.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
     (560033.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
     (560033.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
     (560033.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
     (560034.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
     (560034.4495758876, 6362071.390493258),
     (560034.9495758876, 6362071.390493258),
     (560034.9495758876, 6362071.890493258),
     (560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258)]

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex = True, sharey = True)
    a_points = np.array(points)
    x = a_points[:, 0]
    y = a_points[:, 1]
    axs[0].plot(x,y)
    center, phi, axes = find_ellipse(x, y)
    print "center = ",  center
    print "angle of rotation = ",  phi
    print "axes = ", axes

    axs[1].plot(x, y)
    axs[1].scatter(center[0],center[1], color = 'red', s = 100)
    axs[1].set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
    axs[1].set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())

    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @untubu thanks. By the way, maybe i need to find a buld-in function to fit an ellipse fro a given 2D points. I am looking with google, but do you know some function?

Comment: @Gianni: I don't know of a better algorithm, but I did define a `find_ellipse` function which packages away all the `(xmean, ymean)` shifting, so the code looks nicer.

Comment: in openCV there is cv.FitEllipse2:

this is a short example (= with points i got a message error)
PointArray2D32f = cv.CreateMat(1, len(points), cv.CV_32FC2)

Comment: for (i, (x, y)) in enumerate(points):
PointArray2D32f[0, i] = (x, y)
    # Fits ellipse to current contour.
   (center, size, angle) = cv.FitEllipse2(PointArray2D32f)

Comment: please see the end of my first post (do you think can be correct?)

Comment: @Gianni: Yes, I think the two methods are producing similar results, but expressed differently. `cv.FitEllipse2` reports the same center as `ellipse_center`. What `cv.FitEllipse2` reports as `size` is twice what `ellipse_axis_length` reports. I think this is because `cv.FitEllipse2` is reporting the length of the diameter, while `ellipse_axis_length` is reporting the radius. Finally, `cv.FitEllipse2` seems to be reporting the angle in degress, while `ellipse_angle_of_rotation` is given in radians: `180-(0.708/pi*180)` is roughly 139 degrees which is within spitting distance of 130 degrees.