# How can I score how well an ellipse fits my points?

Tags: python, computational-geometry, shapes, statistical-test

There are dozens of answers on here about how to fit an ellipse to your points, but none seem to suggest ways to quantify the fit. Here's some points and the ellipse fitted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58520339/2009558):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import EllipseModel
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1 = [710.804, 710.117, 709.565, 709.036, 707.839, 707.424, 706.889, 705.913, 705.037, 704.58, 703.758,704.105, 704.552, 704.833, 705.204, 706.027, 706.932, 708.041, 708.849, 709.379, 709.797, 710.272,710.494, 710.871, 711.033, 711.018, 710.804]
y1 = [493.076, 491.902, 491.409, 490.947, 490.396, 491.456, 491.887, 492.917, 494.022, 494.882, 496.085,496.934, 497.723, 498.17, 498.656, 498.929, 499.248, 499.156, 498.768, 498.487, 497.853, 497.212,496.753, 495.957, 495.003, 493.997, 493.076]

points = list(zip(x1,y1))
print(points)
a_points = np.array(points)
x = a_points[:, 0]
y = a_points[:, 1]
ell = EllipseModel()
ell.estimate(a_points)
residuals = ell.residuals(a_points)
xc, yc, a, b, theta = ell.params

print("center = ",  (xc, yc))
print("angle of rotation = ",  theta)
print("axes = ", (a,b))
print('residuals= ', residuals)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axs[0].scatter(x,y)
axs[1].scatter(x, y)
axs[1].scatter(xc, yc, color='red', s=100)
axs[1].set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
axs[1].set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
ell_patch = Ellipse((xc, yc), 2*a, 2*b, theta*180/np.pi, 
edgecolor='red', facecolor='none')
axs[1].add_patch(ell_patch)
plt.show()
```

> center =  (707.7248344321281, 495.2907644989805)

> angle of rotation =  2.1051122302898926

> axes =  (4.783618808884847, 2.92938238506285)

> residuals=  [0.4031933  0.60237637 0.44816215 0.03196744 0.77430711 0.00493033  0.04060345 0.07892221 0.03482433 0.08585788 0.55088573 0.11629398  0.2794519  0.43588704 0.52172484 0.71671995 0.32973538 0.0389334
> 0.19938749 0.35342937 0.2419931  0.24903068 0.1998942  0.18446699
> 0.02005871 0.18610954 0.4031933 ]

[image]

Once I have created a fit, I want to calculate how well it fits the points. I can calculate the residuals using an EllipseModel function. I'm not sure how to use them for this purpose though. I can't use Pearson's correlation as it compares 1D lists. I thought I could calculate the closest point on the ellipse to each of my points by using the ratio of the residual to the distance from point to the ellipse centre of mass and transforming X and Y accordingly. I then thought to try dot product but that seems to require vectors, not points.

Can someone suggest a way to score the fit of the ellipse model?

Comment: Aside from the subjectivity, this appears to be a purely theoretical and mathematical question, not tied to writing code in any particular language. May I suggest [math.se]?

Comment: Here's a paper that uses the ["root-mean-square (RMS) orthogonal distance"](https://zygmuntszpak.github.io/assets/pages/publications/compare_ellipses.pdf) to score the fit of ellipses.

Answer (score 2):

A meaningful rating of the fit is given by one of

- the average distance of the points to the ellipse (can be computed using the `residual` function),
- the RMS distance, which turns out to coincide with the least-squares residual (normalized).

Depending on the goal of assessing the fit, you may consider an absolute value as above, or a relative one, for instance by dividing by the length of the major axis.

The average estimator is more robust than the RMS one.