# Fitting curves in an image and finding intersection points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, curve-fitting

I am working on some images to extract the two curves and find their intersection points. The images vary widely in their appearance as you can see in the attached images.

As for now, doing a sobel and then applying canny edge filter pops them out but not quite sure how to fit curves to them and find the two intersection points (which they will have for sure)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image6.jpg')
grad_x = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, 3)
grad_y = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, 3)
grad = np.sqrt(grad_x**2 + grad_y**2)
grad_norm = (grad * 255 / grad.max()).astype(np.uint8)
grad_norm = cv2.blur(grad_norm,(3,3))
cv2.imshow('Blur', grad_norm)
cv2.waitKey(0)
# Canny Edge Detection
edges = cv2.Canny(image=grad_norm, threshold1=100, threshold2=200) # Canny Edge Detection
# Display Canny Edge Detection Image
cv2.imshow('Canny Edge Detection', edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Original]
[image: End result]
The red points shown above are the ones that I am looking to get to at

Any suggestions?

thanks and Happy New Year to all

Comment: Consider adding tags for `opencv` and `image-processing` to your question to attract the right folk. Try OpenCV `fitEllipse()` maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the fitEllipse() suggestion, I tried applying it with no results, it always returns zero contours.

Comment: Just for kicks, did you try overpainting the other other large, non-ellipse, white objects in black first (just with GIMP/Photoshop) to try not to confuse the ellipse fitting?

Comment: first: what is it we're seeing? why are these lines so faint and broken up? what are all the artefacts and what can be done to prevent them from happening? -- then: following such gently curving lines is not an existing operation in OpenCV. you won't have any luck with Hough and Canny. you can ditch those two right now. Canny is nothing but an edge/ridge enhancer (depending on hardcoded included Sobel or not) that works based on thresholding. that's the wrong operation here.

Comment: Thank you Christoph for your insights, these are images of lens using OCT, so they will show up differently depending on the characteristics of the medium thorugh which they are being imaged. No control over them to improve over the artifacts from happening.
I am quite optimixtic that there much be a way to find out the angle of the elns with resepct to image axis. If not in very faint conditions, but in the ones where you can cearly see the lens.

Comment: I'd recommend exploring something like this: apply a bank of ridge filters that are roughly horizontal, and wide (and use a suitably small angle step). you'd get responses _along_ the line that are consistent with the _angle_ of each response. that oughta help locate those lines more reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, you need to **remove noise**:

- Large components [detection & removal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057324/8618242)
- Noise Filtering (using Filters Gaussian/Median)

2. Then you can **fit an ellipse** as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58520339/8618242).
3. you can divide the set of points into two halves (above the longest axis, under the longest axis), then you fit each of the two sets into a parabola, the algebraic solution of the two equations will be the intersection points.

here is an example with one of your images using basic thresholding and cropping, and ellipse fitting, the challenge in your case lies in better filtering noise to keep only the ellipse/curves.

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage.measure import EllipseModel
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im_id = 1
im_path = f"eliipse_fitting/{im_id}.jpg"
 
original = cv2.imread(im_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = original.copy()
width, height = img.shape

## Cropping to remove large objects
img = img[width//3:2*width//3, height//3: 2*height//3]

## Thresholding
th = 50
img[img>=th] = 255
img[img<th] = 0

## TODO: Add Noise Filtering, and Large Objects Removal
nonzero_indices = np.transpose(np.nonzero(img))
points = [(index[1], index[0]) for index in nonzero_indices]

a_points = np.array(points)
x = a_points[:, 0]
y = a_points[:, 1]

ell = EllipseModel()
ell.estimate(a_points)

xc, yc, a, b, theta = ell.params

print("center = ",  (xc, yc))
print("angle of rotation = ",  theta)
print("axes = ", (a,b))

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) 

plt.imshow(original, cmap='gray')

x0 = xc+height//3
y0 = yc+width//3

plt.scatter(x0, y0, color='green', s=10)
ell_patch = Ellipse((x0, y0), 2*a, 2*b, theta*180/np.pi, edgecolor='green', facecolor='none')

ax.add_patch(ell_patch)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Bilal, this is exactly what I am looking for, much simpler. Worked great with some very small edits on my end.